# How to create service url to get demographic data and then tie up the demographic data with zip code?

Tags: web-mapping

I want to create a Map tool like https://www.eddmexperts.com/eddm-map-tool.  This site is using ArcGIS map service but I did not understand where I can get the service URL they are using to get demographic data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the demographic data is coming from this REST URL:

https://agsutils.adc4gis.com/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/EDDM_Availability/MapServer

I was able to find this by opening up the Web Console in my browser and executing web app functionality.

Comment: Yeah, that's right but I did not find any Url like that in ArcGIS map service area.